# Structural Coupling of Test

Tags: architecture, testing

In Clean Architecture, Robert Martin talks about the necessity to "decouple the structure of the tests from the structure of the application". He notes that a test suite that has a test class for every production class/a set of test methods for every production method is deeply coupled, and thus fragile. He thus advocates for a testing API, which could decouple this structural dependency.

I was wondering how such a testing API and the test suite would look like with respect to structuring and naming of the tests? Also, such a decoupling seems to be at odds with the often encountered naming conventions of tests in the form of

> [UnitOfWork__StateUnderTest__ExpectedBehavior]/[NameOfTheClassUnderTestTests]

as suggested in this highly upvoted answer on [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/155436/unit-test-naming-best-practices), doesn't it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Naming**

Let's address the naming first. `Unit_StateOrEvent_Behavior` is a reasonable naming convention in my opinion. Just remember that a unit is not necessarily a class.

The names of your tests should express the requirements they test, not the names of the class(es) that implement the requirements. This also applies to the name of the test class.

You won't typically have a direct mapping of test-cases to methods (or of test classes to classes under test), because there generally won't be a one-to-one mapping of requirements to methods/classes.

**Test API**

Unit tests are necessarily coupled to the public interface of the unit they are testing. This is okay, because if your system is loosely coupled, only the tests relevant to that unit are affected by changes.

From the context of the quote you provided, I would infer that Martin's concern there is the coupling of integration/acceptance tests to the inner structure of the system, or to details such as the GUI (as discussed on the previous page). If this happens, a change to a class may no longer just require a change to a few unit tests, but to a potentially large number of higher level tests.

To avoid this, these tests should access the system through a stable API. The interactors are a good candidate. But sometimes the interactors may not be sufficient for your testing needs: they may themselves not be stable enough, require executing difficult-to-mock or expensive logic or constrain you for other reasons (e.g. security).

For these cases, Martin proposes to provide an extended API that is only used by the tests. This API then shields the tests from the internals, the same way interactors shield the UI.